# Error "app install debug failed" while react-native run-android

Tags: node.js, react-native, android-emulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ea4Q.png)[Problem occur on its own](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKh7R.png)

[Dont know why this happening my emulator is not installing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzEj1.png)

Comment: open project in android studio, update gradle. and run the app

Comment: Please post your error instead of images.